# Excel: Output values that appear in both columns to another column

Tags: excel

I have two columns of email addresses (A & B) and would like to determine which emails appear in both list. Everything I googled either highlighted matching cells, requires third party tools like Kutools or only matches if the same value is on the same row.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |  |
| 5 | 7 |  |
|  | 8 |  |
|  | 9 |  |

I assumed this was a common thing to do in Excel, but can't seem to find a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)))
```

[image]

Without Office 365 put this in C1 and copy down till empty:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A5)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A5,B:B,0))),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

[image]